# Android notification ringtone does not stop even after it is canceled

Tags: android, notifications, kotlin

I have a written a service which fires a notification with an alarm ringtone at a specific time. The notification works as intended, however, the problem is that even after I cancel the notification or click on it from the notification bar, it continues to play the ringtone. Meaning that the notification cancels if I swipe across it, and it opens a pending intent if I click on it. However, the sound/ringtone keeps on playing even after I have performed either of the aforementioned actions (swipe, click).

My code for firing the notification is as follows (it's written in Kotlin):

```
private fun fireNotification() {
    var anotherIntent:Intent=Intent(this,ReminderActivity::class.java)
    var p1:PendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,anotherIntent,0)
    val defaultSoundUri=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

    var notifyManager: NotificationManager =getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    var notification:Notification=NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Medicine Time")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentText("Time to take your medicine")
            .setContentIntent(p1)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build()
    notifyManager.notify(0,notification)
}
```

Any help in the matter would be greatly appreciated, thanks!